# How to Make a Animation in a Bar That Inside the Bar That Moves to the Left While the Actual Loading Bar Moves to the Right

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

Basically I want to make something similar to this gmail bar https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYWhj.gif.

Right now I am able to make the whole bar and make it progress

These are 3 view properties.

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) UIView *progressBarView;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) UIImageView *progressBarBackground;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) UIImageView *progressBar;
```

and I add progressBarBackground and progressBar as subview in progressBarView.

For bar progress animation I just use

```
CGRect frame = self.progressBar.frame;
frame.size.width = MAX(kProgressBarMinWidth, kProgressBarWidth * self.progress);
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                 animations:^{
                     self.progressBar.frame = frame;
                 }];
```

But I am having problem adding that left to right animation in the gif. Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

That looks to me to be a pattern-based color fill, and then animating the origin of the pattern. Take a look at the `UIColor` class method `colorwithPatternImage`